# The tensorflow module is not visible inside swift

Tags: swift, tensorflow, swift-for-tensorflow

I am trying out the `Tensorflow` for `Swift` announced in TFDevSummit'18.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yze693W4MaU

When I try to import the `TensorFlow` module inside `Swift`, `Swift` is unable to find the module and throws the following error message.

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.1 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.39.1). Type :help for assistance.
1> import TensorFlow
```

> error: repl.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'TensorFlow'
>   import TensorFlow

I am new to `Swift`. Is there any reference how to install the `TensorFlow` module in `Swift`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have got clarification from the author of the library that it is not yet available and it will only be available in April.

Reference: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19#issuecomment-377670527

Answer (score 1):

Swift for Tensorflow is not yet released for public.

You can follow these links to install and use it:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md
- https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Usage.md